# Android Studio doesn't recognize my resource directory

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created an Android Resource Directory, which contains xml file with some menu changes. Whenever I trying to use MenuInflater, Android Studio doesn't recognize my directory, which is called the menu. I've already tried to rebuild the project, what should I do with it?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.note_add); <- the "menu" is a directory, that is not being seen by android studio
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

- This directory is created in res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check if menu directory is inside the res folder